# Windows Batch: can't exit from called subroutine- always returns even if goto:END

Tags: batch-file

I have a subroutines which is called to check `ERRORLEVEL`.
The subroutine calls other subroutines to log msgs, send email, then Exit out of the script.  It goes to `:END`, then returns to the stmt after the call

```
@echo off
echo starting...
call:checkTime
echo +++ after CT
GOTO:END

:checkTime
echo the time is %TIME%
goto:END
goto:EOF

:END
```

Comment: You are not really using MS-DOS, are you?

Comment: DOS Batch script in Windows 2003.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "DOS" Batch script (in Windows Server 2003). That's still a Windows batch script

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: the question is: Is that expected behavior?  To return from End?

Answer (score 5):

The question is poorly worded, but I think I understand (especially if I concentrate on the title)

**My interpretation of your problem:**

At various points in your batch file, you check the ERRORLEVEL. Whenever you detect an error, you want to perform some standard error processing, and then exit the batch script. You attempted to create a subroutine to do the standard processing, but the subroutine returns to the caller instead of exiting the script. Your question is, how do you force your error processing routine to exit instead of returning to caller?

**Answer:**

If none of your error detection occurs within a called subroutine, then you can simply GOTO your error processor instead of CALLing it.

If you want to be able to call the routine and exit from within another called routine, then you can continue to use the `CALL` statement, but terminate your error routine with `EXIT` instead of `GOTO :EOF` or `GOTO :END`.

**Addendum in response to comment**

Yes, GOTO cannot pass parameters, and a CALLed routine will always return to the caller (unless the routine ends with EXIT)

And yes, EXIT will close the current CMD shell, which will usually close the console window.

BUT... you can have the batch file execute itself through another CMD shell, so that EXIT does not close the window!

The only potential drawback to this that I see is changes to the environment will be lost once the batch file (and the CMD shell that is running it) terminates. That may or may not be a problem for you.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" equ "_GO_" goto :main
cmd /c ^""%~f0" _GO_ %*^"
exit /b

:main
shift /1
echo %%1=%1  %%2=%2

echo before call
call :exitRoutine
:: should not get here
echo after call
exit /b

:exitRoutine
echo exiting batch file witin exitRoutine
exit
```

Comment: if I GOTO the error routine, I can't pass parameters to the routine, correct?  If i EXIT the CMD window will close.  Is what is happening expected behavior?  Ie.  called routine GOTO:END  returns to caller? Thanks

Comment: @chrys2012 - I updated the answer with a solution I think will work for you

Comment: @dbenham: +1 Interesting solution, Dave! An `EXIT` may also be used this way to break any pending IF/FOR structure at any level, and the process will continue at the calling code. May I suggest the macro `set break=exit`? (We already used this idea in WHILE macro)

Comment: The question is NOT poorly worded. It's very clear. And it refers to a general and known problem! It's not the questioners's problem in particular. So, no need for interpretation. Next time please don't try to answer if you have not understood the question, esp. in that length. It's very annoying.

Comment: @Apostolos - The body of a question should be able to stand on its own, and it should clearly state the question. The body of this "question" only states what the OP is doing, and describes the resultant behavior. It never states what the intended behavior is, nor does it ask a question. The title does imply a goal, but never states it out right, and also does not ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is the expected behavior: a subroutine called via `CALL` command may end in three different ways: executing `EXIT [/B]`, executing `GOTO :EOF` or just reaching the end of the file. All three ways cause to return to the calling program. By the while, "GOTO command now accepts a target label of :EOF which transfers control to the end of the current batch script file.  This is an easy way to exit a batch script file without defining a label." (from `GOTO /?`), so really the second and third methods are the same.

If you want to sometimes return from the subroutine, but other times to terminate the calling program, then your *subprogram* can NOT be executed via `CALL`, but in other different way. If you want to pass parameters to the subprogram, then it must be a separate .BAT file that will be executed via its name with parameters and NO call, for example:

```
subprogram param1 param2 ...
```

This way, in order for this subprogram to "return" to the calling program, it must know to wich Batch file and in what line it must return. This information may be set by the calling program via variables; the calling program must also determine if it is running in normal way or because the return of the false subroutine. You may do that this way:

**main.bat:**

```
@echo off
rem If this is a false subroutine return: complete it
if "%1" == "return" goto %2
rem Do my usual business
rem . . .
rem Execute the subprogram as subroutine
set caller=main
set returnPoint=label23
subprogram param1 param2
:label23
rem Continue after subprogram return...
```

**subprogram.bat:**

```
rem Do my business
rem . . .
rem To return to the caller:
%caller% return %returnPoint%
rem . . .
rem To terminate here, execute EXIT /B, GOTO :EOF, or just reach the end
```

Sorry, there is no easy way to do this...

Comment: "By the while, "GOTO command now accepts a target label of :EOF which transfers control to the end of the current batch script file. This is an easy way to exit a batch script file without defining a label."

Comment: I use GOTO:EOF at the end of each subroutine to enxit the subroutine, not exit the batch script file.

Comment: @chrys2012 - `GOTO:EOF` and `EXIT /B` are synonymous - they do exactly the same thing. The only difference is `EXIT /B` has the option to specify the ERRORLEVEL return code. `GOTO:EOF` is old syntax that predates the introduction of  `EXIT /B`.